# How to get all sub collection data to Widget with StreamBuilder in Firebase + Firestore + Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

In flutter, I use Firebase Firestore to save data. I created the root collection as **Users** and in that collection, each user has a subcollection named by **Books**.

This is my Firebase Cloud Firestore

[image]

I tried to get all users all books with a button click as below

```
getUserBooks() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").get().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(result.id)
          .collection("Books")
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          BooksModel booksModel = BooksModel.fromDocument(result);

          print("--------------------- Books ---------------------\n"
              "id: ${booksModel.bookID}\n"
              "name: ${booksModel.bookName}\n"
              "image: ${booksModel.bookImage}");
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This is model class

```
class BooksModel {
  final String bookID;
  final String bookName;
  final String bookImage;

  BooksModel({
    this.bookID,
    this.bookName,
    this.bookImage,
  });

  factory BooksModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return BooksModel(
      bookID: documentSnapshot['bookID'],
      bookName: documentSnapshot['bookName'],
      bookImage: documentSnapshot['bookImage'],
    );
  }
}
```

I used the below code to get the book details according to a single user but **I want to get all users books details to that widget**. How can I change the code?

```
_usersBookListWidget() {
  return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(userID)
          .collection('Books')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return !snapshot.hasData
            ? Container()
            : snapshot.data.docs.length.toString() == "0"
            ? Container(
          height: 250.0,
          width: 200.0,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "You have no books yet",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .headline6
                        .fontSize),
              ),
              Image.asset(
                'assets/icons/icon_no_books_yet.png',
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            BooksModel booksModel =
            BooksModel.fromDocument(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(booksModel.bookID),
                Text(booksModel.bookName),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct way yet to get all sub-collections for all the documents in a single collection like in your case.
First you have to query your `users` collection, then after that, for each user document, you run a separate query. Here's a pseudo code:

1- StreamBuilder (`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection.('Users').snapshots()`,
Here you can display info about every user in a listview if you want, but you have to capture the `document.id`, because you will need it for the next step.

2- you create a widget called userBooks for example, for this widget, you pass to it the `document.id` from the previous step. Now you have all the user IDs in your database, and since the subcollection is called `books` and doesn't change, you use this for another streambuilder, with this collection reference:
`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection.('Users').doc(document.id).collection('Books').snapshots()`. This will give you the result you want.

---

For your code snippet to work, you need to use async\await, like this:

```
getUserBooks() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").get().then((querySnapshot) async {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(result.id)
          .collection("Books")
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          BooksModel booksModel = BooksModel.fromDocument(result);

          print("--------------------- Books ---------------------\n"
              "id: ${booksModel.bookID}\n"
              "name: ${booksModel.bookName}\n"
              "image: ${booksModel.bookImage}");
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This will work for getting them in a single button.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. I will try to implement this answer ❤

Comment: Check out the edited response, it would work for your existing function `getUserBooks()`